# Unable to create a Splitter's bean for spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-bean

Spring is unable to create a Splitter bean, I'm getting this error related to `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` that extends `AbstractMessageSplitter`  :

```
 ERROR||           main(1)||Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'splitterTasks': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.SplitterFactoryBean#0' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.SplitterFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: failed to initialize MessageHandler; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.tasky.TaskyApplication.main(TaskyApplication.java:20) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.SplitterFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: failed to initialize MessageHandler; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: failed to initialize MessageHandler; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:242) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:172) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:57) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.onInit(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:163) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.onInit(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:82) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:176) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:239) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:172) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:57) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
```

Here is my spring integration configuration :

```
<int:channel id="tasksChannel" />

<int:service-activator ref="testService"
        method="storeAllTasks" input-channel="tasksChannel"
        output-channel="savedTasksChannel" />

<int:channel id="savedTasksChannel" />

<int:splitter id="splitterTasks" ref="tasksSplitter" input-channel="savedTasksChannel" output-channel="splittedTasksChannel" />

<int:channel id="splittedTasksChannel" />
```

And here is my splitter's definition :

```
@Service(value = "tasksSplitter")
public class TasksSplitter extends AbstractMessageSplitter {

    private final LogService logger;

    public TasksSplitter(LogServiceFactory logFactory) {
        this.logger = logFactory.getLogger(TasksSplitter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object splitMessage(Message<?> message) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldCopyRequestHeaders() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What am I not configuring correctly ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a proper stack trace? This one "ERROR||           main(1)||" is not readable and not so useful. Would be great to see some pointers to the code lines.

Comment: The `BeanCreationException` of the splitterTasks is just a aftereffect of the `NullPointerException` during the instantiation of the `MessageHandler`. Do you create the `MessageHandler` yourself? If so: please share that code.

Comment: @Artem Bilan I've updated the stack trace. @LazerBass I'm just extending `AbstractMessageSplitter` for my `TasksSplitter`

Comment: While this indeed needs more info, it still looks like a bug from what is already provided.```Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.onInit(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:163) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]``` While there can very well be some missconfiguratuion, the NPE from  AbstractMessageProducingHandler is a bug.

Comment: Oleg, can you point out, please, what causes that NPE? What the bug do you see in the `AbstractMessageProducingHandler`? Thanks

Comment: The stack trace points to this line: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/v4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/handler/AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java#L163. That `this.messagingTemplate` because it is initialized in the beginning and as a `final` property. There is definitely something else going on. For example some proxiyng with AspectJ or anything else. Would be great to have a minimal project to let us to reproduce locally and play with that from the debug. I see you use Spring Boot, so, please, share on GitHub!

Comment: Apologies for the delayed answer, I managed to solve it by changing `@Service` to `@Component`. I'm unable to share the project because it's a corporate one within the organization's standard technical framework. I'm a beginner at Spring, but from what I could understand, they're using AOP to manage some correlation id which was the NPE.